# RoleLastUsed object missing in list-roles boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, roles

I am using python boto3 version 1.12.1

Would like to get "RoleLastUsed" for each role.

Observed:

1. RoleLastUsed object is not found in list_roles API.
2. RoleLastUsed object is found in get_role API.

Expected:

RoleLastUsed object should be available in both get_role and list_roles API.

Documentdation:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_roles
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_role

Thanks

Comment: I would raise an issue at the boto3 GitHub page. The underlying ListRoles API does return RoleLastUsed, so it sounds like this should be available to you with boto3 list_roles (and the awscli equivalent, which similarly does not appear to return the last used date).